# Coercivity and PS condition implies global minimizer

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, coercive

I am unable to get any intution to prove the following statement.
Any $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ which is coercive and satisfies PS condition has a global minimizer, provided $X$ is a reflexive Banach space.

Comment: Plese define " PS condition".

Comment: Palais–Smale compactness condition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palais%E2%80%93Smale_compactness_condition

Comment: No such explanation I have found there. I tried to prove by definition but unable.

Comment: My link was not intended to provide a solution to your problem, I was asking whether that is the PS condition being referred to in your question. Readers don't even know what your question (PS condition) is.

Comment: The strong formulation defined in your wiki link is the PS condition in my question. Thanks

Comment: The proof uses Ekeland's variational principle, see Ekeland's paper [On the variational principle] https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82187504.pdf in Section 5